# it only works when I make year into a global variable, despite using only one main function

Tags: c

In this code when I change the position of the variable int year inside the main function the ouutput printed line replace every year with 1792 despite that I don't have 1792 at all

Code with `year` as local variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int year = 0;
    int rp1970 = 73, rp1980 = 66, rp1990 = 49, rp2000 = 38, rp2010 = 29;
    int up1970 = 27, up1980 = 34, up1990 = 51, up2000 = 62, up2010 = 71;
    float t1970=10.44, t1980=13.14, t1990=17.57, t2000=23.30, t2010=28.60;
    float rn1970=7.62, rn1980=8.67, rn1990=8.67, rn2000=8.85, rn2010=8.29;
    float un1970=2.82, un1980=4.47, un1990=8.90, un2000=14.45, un2010=20.31;

    printf("                                 welcome to population data base for years, 1970,1980,1990,2000,2010 ");
    char specific, choice;
    do {
        printf("\n\nenter a year(choose between 1970,1980,1990,2000,2010):");
        scanf("%d",&year);
        while (year!=1970 && year!=1980 && year!=1990 && year!=2000 && year!=2010) {
            printf("\nwrong input\n enter a year(choose between 1970,1980,1990,2000,2010):");
            scanf("%d", &year);
        }
        if (year == 1970) {
            printf("\npress t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
            scanf("%s", &specific);
            while (specific!='t' && specific!='T'&& specific!='r'&& specific!='R'&& specific!='u'&& specific!='U') {
                printf("\nwrong input\n press t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
                scanf("%s", &specific);
            }
            if (specific == 't' || specific == 'T') {
                printf("\ntotal population of year %d is %.2fm ",year,t1970);
            }
            if (specific == 'r' || specific == 'R') {
                printf("\nrural population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population", year, rn1970, rp1970);
            }
            if (specific == 'u' || specific == 'U') {
                printf("\nurban population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population", year, un1970, up1970);
            }
        }
        else if (year == 1980) {
            printf("\npress t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
            scanf("%s", &specific);
            while (specific!='t' && specific!='T'&& specific!='r'&& specific!='R'&& specific!='u'&& specific!='U') {
                printf("\nwrong input\n press t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
                scanf("%s",&specific);
            }
            if (specific=='t'||specific=='T') {
                printf("\ntotal population of year %d is %.2fm ",year,t1980);
            }
            if (specific=='r'||specific=='R') {
                printf("\nrural population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,rn1980,rp1980);
            }
            if (specific=='u'||specific=='U') {
                printf("\nurban population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,un1980,up1980);
            }
        }
        else if (year==1990) {
            printf("\npress t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
            scanf("%s", &specific);
            while (specific!='t' && specific!='T'&& specific!='r'&& specific!='R'&& specific!='u'&& specific!='U') {
                printf("\nwrong input\n press t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
                scanf("%s", &specific);
            }
            if (specific=='t'||specific=='T') {
                printf("\ntotal population of year %d is %.2fm",year,t1990);
            }
            if (specific=='r'||specific=='R') {
                printf("\nrural population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,rn1990,rp1990);
            }
            if (specific=='u'||specific=='U') {
                printf("\nurban population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,un1990,up1990);
            }
        }
        else if (year==2000) {
            printf("\npress t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
            scanf("%s", &specific);
            while (specific!='t' && specific!='T'&& specific!='r'&& specific!='R'&& specific!='u'&& specific!='U') {
                printf("\nwrong input\n press t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
                scanf("%s", &specific);
            }
            if (specific=='t'||specific=='T') {
                printf("\ntotal population of year %d is %.2fm", year, t2000);
            }
            if (specific=='r'||specific=='R') {
                printf("\nrural population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,rn2000,rp2000);
            }
            if (specific=='u'||specific=='U') {
                printf("\nurban population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,un2000,up2000);
            }
        }
        else if (year==2010) {
            printf("\npress t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
            scanf("%s", &specific);
            while (specific!='t' && specific!='T'&& specific!='r'&& specific!='R'&& specific!='u'&& specific!='U') {
                printf("\nwrong input\n press t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
                scanf("%s",&specific);
            }
            if (specific=='t'||specific=='T') {
                printf("\ntotal population of year %d is %.2fm",year,t2010);
            }
            if (specific=='r'||specific=='R') {
                printf("\nrural population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,rn2010,rp2010);
            }
            if (specific=='u'||specific=='U') {
                printf("\nurban population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,un2010,up2010);
            }
        }

        printf("\n\ndo you want to extract more data, press y for yes n for no: ");
        scanf("%s", &choice);
        while ((choice!='y'&&choice!='Y')&&(choice!='n'&&choice!='N')) {
            printf("\nwrong input\n do you want tto extract more data, press y for yes n for no: ");
            scanf("%s", &choice);
        }
    } while (choice=='y'||choice=='Y');

    printf("\n\nthank you for using our services");

    return 0;
}
```

Code with `year` as global variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int year = 0;

int main() {
    int rp1970=73, rp1980=66, rp1990=49, rp2000=38, rp2010= 29;
    int up1970=27, up1980=34, up1990=51, up2000=62, up2010=71;
    float t1970=10.44, t1980=13.14, t1990=17.57, t2000=23.30, t2010=28.60;
    float rn1970=7.62, rn1980=8.67, rn1990=8.67, rn2000=8.85, rn2010=8.29;
    float un1970=2.82, un1980=4.47, un1990=8.90, un2000=14.45, un2010=20.31;


    printf("                                 welcome to population data base for years, 1970,1980,1990,2000,2010 ");
    char specific, choice;
    do{
        printf("\n\nenter a year(choose between 1970,1980,1990,2000,2010):");
        scanf("%d",&year);
        while(year!=1970 && year!=1980 && year!=1990 && year!=2000 && year!=2010){
            printf("\nwrong input\n enter a year(choose between 1970,1980,1990,2000,2010):");
            scanf("%d",&year);
        }
        if(year==1970){
            printf("\npress t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
            scanf("%s",&specific);
            while(specific!='t' && specific!='T'&& specific!='r'&& specific!='R'&& specific!='u'&& specific!='U'){
                printf("\nwrong input\n press t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
                scanf("%s",&specific);
            }
            if(specific=='t'||specific=='T'){
                printf("\ntotal population of year %d is %.2fm ",year,t1970);
            }
            if(specific=='r'||specific=='R'){
                printf("\nrural population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,rn1970,rp1970);
            }
            if(specific=='u'||specific=='U'){
                printf("\nurban population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,un1970,up1970);
            }
        }
        else if(year==1980){
            printf("\npress t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
            scanf("%s",&specific);
            while(specific!='t' && specific!='T'&& specific!='r'&& specific!='R'&& specific!='u'&& specific!='U'){
                printf("\nwrong input\n press t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
                scanf("%s",&specific);
            }
            if(specific=='t'||specific=='T'){
                printf("\ntotal population of year %d is %.2fm ",year,t1980);
            }
            if(specific=='r'||specific=='R'){
                printf("\nrural population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,rn1980,rp1980);
            }
            if(specific=='u'||specific=='U'){
                printf("\nurban population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,un1980,up1980);
            }
        }
        else if(year==1990){
            printf("\npress t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
            scanf("%s",&specific);
            while(specific!='t' && specific!='T'&& specific!='r'&& specific!='R'&& specific!='u'&& specific!='U'){
                printf("\nwrong input\n press t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
                scanf("%s",&specific);
            }
            if(specific=='t'||specific=='T'){
                printf("\ntotal population of year %d is %.2fm",year,t1990);
            }
            if(specific=='r'||specific=='R'){
                printf("\nrural population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,rn1990,rp1990);
            }
            if(specific=='u'||specific=='U'){
                printf("\nurban population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,un1990,up1990);
            }
        }
        else if(year==2000){
            printf("\npress t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
            scanf("%s",&specific);
            while(specific!='t' && specific!='T'&& specific!='r'&& specific!='R'&& specific!='u'&& specific!='U'){
                printf("\nwrong input\n press t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
                scanf("%s",&specific);
            }
            if(specific=='t'||specific=='T'){
                printf("\ntotal population of year %d is %.2fm",year,t2000);
            }
            if(specific=='r'||specific=='R'){
                printf("\nrural population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,rn2000,rp2000);
            }
            if(specific=='u'||specific=='U'){
                printf("\nurban population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,un2000,up2000);
            }
        }
        else if(year==2010){
            printf("\npress t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
            scanf("%s",&specific);
            while(specific!='t' && specific!='T'&& specific!='r'&& specific!='R'&& specific!='u'&& specific!='U'){
                printf("\nwrong input\n press t for total population r for rural population u for urban population: ");
                scanf("%s",&specific);
            }
            if(specific=='t'||specific=='T'){
                printf("\ntotal population of year %d is %.2fm",year,t2010);
            }
            if(specific=='r'||specific=='R'){
                printf("\nrural population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,rn2010,rp2010);
            }
            if(specific=='u'||specific=='U'){
                printf("\nurban population of year %d is %.2fm and it is %d%% of total population",year,un2010,up2010);
            }
        }

        printf("\n\ndo you want to extract more data, press y for yes n for no: ");
        scanf("%s",&choice);
        while((choice!='y'&&choice!='Y')&&(choice!='n'&&choice!='N')){
            printf("\nwrong input\n do you want tto extract more data, press y for yes n for no: ");
            scanf("%s",&choice);
        }
    }while (choice=='y'||choice=='Y');

    printf("\n\nthank you for using our services");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image: output]

the output should be : rural/ urban population of (the year entered by the user) is.....

it only works when the variable int year is global

[image]

Comment: try to limit line length. No one likes horizontal scroll. And put more spaces to make it readable

Comment: When you learn about arrays and structures, you'll be able to make your code easier to read with less repetition.  I assume you've simply not covered these yet (and it might be as well not to disillusion me if you have).

Comment: You should also write the code for obtaining 'total', 'rural' or 'urban' once, before you run tests on which year was requested.  That way, you avoid repeating the code N times.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has nothing to do with the placement of the `year` variable. You are experiencing "undefined behavior" where anything can happen.

The real issue is that you are using the wrong format specifier to read in a char:

```
char specific;
scanf("%s",&specific);
```

The `specific` variable is only large enough to hold 1 `char` but you are telling `scanf` you want a string of chars. Even if you only enter 1 char in stdin, `scanf` will add a trailing `\0`.

To scan a char:

```
scanf(" %c",&specific);
```

You must also do this for `choice`.

Comment: first of all I want to thank you a looooot for taking the time and reading all of that. I noticed before that using %c for scanning choice for do while loops causes problems and sometimes it doesn't work at all ( it causes problems with cache or smth I don't really know) the teacher said that we have to use get char(); it didn't work for me, then someone told me to use %s and it worked very well for do whiles, then I started to use it instead of %c for everything. now I tried your solution it solved the year 1792 problem but the program keeps repeating wrong input twice, can u please try it

Comment: @EddAhmed The problem you were probably having with `%c` is that it does not read the newline. So if you hit "t<enter>" the `scanf` will read the "t" but leave the newline character in the input buffer. So the next time you use `%c` it will read the newline char. The solution is to put a space before `%c`. This tells `scanf` to skip all whitespace before the char. Make sure you have that space in there.